# How to close all quicktime windows from zsh?

Tags: quicktime, zsh

I wish to close all the open windows of Quicktime from zsh, i.e. I want to automate from zsh the following two operations that I am currently doing manually:

1. Bring Quicktime in *forefront* (i.e. I don't know if that is the appropriate word)
2. Hit CMD + W

Comment: You can’t directly control the GUI from a shell.  You can call an AppleScript from the shell, but this is ultimately an AppleScript question

Comment: You made my day! I made an Applescript and I just call it from zsh. Problem solved!

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

It is not possible to directly control the GUI from a shell, as suggested.
Hence, I prepared the following AppleScript

```
tell application "QuickTime Player"
    if it is running then
        delay 0.5
        close every window of it
    end if
end tell
return
```

that can be conveniently called from a `zsh` shell with

```
osascript ~/QuickTimeClose.scpt
```

assuming that the script is called `QuickTimeClose.scpt` and it is located in your `HOME` folder.

Comment: Thanks, this was super helpful. Was able to define the Apple Script directly in the shell by using `osascript`'s ability to accept `-e` arguments. In my case simply using `quit` instead of the whole `if` block / closing of specifically the windows. (Since I wanted the application itself to completely quit.)